# XCTAssertEquals with two dicts in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xctest

I am doing the exercism.io programming exercises and the tests I have to perform on my code has the goal to compare to dicts with each other. The sourcecode of the exercise can be found here https://github.com/exercism/xswift/tree/master/word-count

[image: Test code for comparing two dicts]

As of what I have understood bridgeToObjectiveC is apples internal methods for doing things and therefore they have been removed. With them i get `'[S : T]' does not have a member named 'bridgeToObjectiveC'` which is very understandable if they have removed it.

Without the method using only the params in the AssertEquals call i get `'[S : T]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`. Is two dicts not comparable in Swift? How would I do to get them comparable?

Comment: Please include code samples as text. They should be pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check equality of dictionaries as long as the values are `Equatable`. Modify `XCTAssertEqualDictionaries` to include a generic constraint:

```
func XCTAssertEqualDictionaries<S, T: Equatable>(first: [S:T], _ second: [S:T]) {
    XCTAssert(first == second)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a vert convenient way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
XCTAssertEqual(swiftDict as NSObject, objCDict as NSObject)
```

Forces the compiler to just chill out and call the `isEqual:` method on both.

Answer (score 3):

No, Swift dictionaries are not directly comparable. For the purposes of unit-testing, you can either do manual comparisons of their sizes and pair-wise element comparisons, or you can do the easy thing and create `NSDictionary`s out of them and compare them that way.

Answer (score 0):

In case of mixed type dictionaries you can compare each key individually, if you know the keys and their types upfront. However, this does not generalize into a universal comparison function.

```swift
let dict1: [String: Any] = ["a": "a", "b": 2]
let dict2: [String: Any] = ["a": "a", "b": 2]
XCTAssertEqual(dict1["a"] as? String, dict2["a"] as? String)
XCTAssertEqual(dict1["b"] as? Int, dict2["b"] as? Int)
```